# Are there EditorConfig properties for formatting comments?

Tags: c#, editorconfig

I did a custom .editorconfig file which I apllied the nameing conventions like(interfaces should begins with I and then Uppercase) and works just fine (except the fact that it doesnt fix the names automatically after i run code cleanup). and i was wondering if there were a set of rules to control the comments, for example, the line should starts with space then the comments, and it should start new line after 100 character.

I dont want to use third party softwares, I would like to use vanilla visual studio

Answer (score 0):

In terms of standard ones (non-extension ones), there are some ideas for proposed ones in https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties#ideas-for-domain-specific-properties, which currently includes `block_comment`, `line_comment`, `block_comment_start`, `block_comment_end`. You may be able to find related issue tickets / discussions in https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues?q=is%3Aissue+label%3A%22feature+request%22+comments+is%3Aopen.

In terms of non-standard ones, consult the documentation / properties reference docs for your specific editorconfig tool. Ex. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/EditorConfig_Index.html.